# Does replication in Redis provide high availability too? Apart from increasing read performance

Tags: redis, replication, master-slave

While going through redis documentation : [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/docs/management/replication/#:%7E:text=Replication%20can%20be%20used%20both%20for%20scalability%2C%20to%20have%20multiple%20replicas%20for%20read%2Donly%20queries%20(for%20example%2C%20slow%20O(N)%20operations%20can%20be%20offloaded%20to%20replicas)%2C%20or%20simply%20for%20improving%20data%20safety%20and%20high%20availability.), it says replication provides high-availability.

My understanding is that replication is used when we need to improve Read performance. It does not improve availability or write performance. But the documentation (link included above) says:

> Replication can be used both for scalability, to have multiple
> replicas for read-only queries (for example, slow O(N) operations can
> be offloaded to replicas), or simply for improving data safety and
> **high availability**

How does replication provide high availability? Don't we need redis in cluster/sentinel mode for high availability?

Comment: "Availability _of the data_" is what it is referring to, not necessarily "availability of client operations"